# How do I use tkinter PhotoImage within a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a draughts/checkers game in python, and I have a problem that I can't find a solution for online when creating the pieces. My code is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *

board = []

white_pieces = []
black_pieces = []

class GUI(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        self.game_board()

    def game_board(self):
        for y in range(8):
            for x in range(8):
                board.append(Button(root, width = 4, height = 2, bg = "#000000" if (x % 2 == 0 and y % 2 != 0) or (y % 2 == 0 and x % 2 != 0) else "#FFFFFF", state = DISABLED))
                board[-1].grid(row = y + 1, column = x + 1, sticky = N+E+S+W)
                root.rowconfigure(x+1, weight = 1)
                root.columnconfigure(y+1, weight = 1)

        for i in range(8):
            Label(root, bg = "#C9C9C9", text = i+1).grid(row = 0, column = i+1, sticky = N+E+S+W)
            root.rowconfigure(i, weight = 1)

        for i in range(8):
            Label(root, width = 2, bg = "#C9C9C9", text = chr(i+97).title()).grid(row = i+1, column = 0, sticky = N+E+S+W)
            root.columnconfigure(i, weight = 1)


class piece(PhotoImage):
    def __init__(self, position, master = None):
        self.name = "white.png"
        self.position = position


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Draughts")
    window = GUI(root)
    black = PhotoImage("black.png")
    white = PhotoImage("white.png")
    for i in range(24):
        if ((i % 8) % 2 == 0 and (i // 8) % 2 != 0) or ((i % 8) % 2 != 0 and (i // 8) % 2 == 0):
            black_pieces.append(piece([i // 8, i % 8],black))
            board[i].config(image = black_pieces[-1], state = NORMAL)
        else:
            i += 40
            if ((i % 8) % 2 == 0 and (i // 8) % 2 != 0) or ((i % 8) % 2 != 0 and (i // 8) % 2 == 0):
                white_pieces.append(piece([i // 8, i % 8],black))
                board[i].config(image = white_pieces[-1], state = NORMAL)
    root.mainloop()
```

I am trying to use `PhotoImage` as the subject of a class (not sure if that's the right way to put it), but it doesn't work. I don't know if what I'm attempting is the right way to go about it, but I want to create 'Pieces' in the squares I need them in for checkers. If I change the `image = black_pieces[-1]` to `bg = "green"` in the line:`board[i].config(image = black_pieces[-1], state = NORMAL)`, then the correct squares get a green background, so the problems lies in the images (I have png images of black and white draughts pieces saved in the same directory called black.png and white.png). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What haven't told us what the problem with the images actually *is*. I assume it's the same problem everyone else has, meaning that the images simply don't show up?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: Hmm, well, taking a closer look at your code, your problem isn't the usual one.

Comment: How do you mean? When I run the code the images don't appear in the buttons, however as to the underlying cause of the problem I am not sure

Comment: Usually the problem is that people don't hold references to the images and they get garbage collected, but that's not the case here. I *think* the problem is simply that you forgot to call `PhotoImage.__init__` in your `piece` constructor.

Comment: Ok so I added `PhotoImage.__init__(self, "white.png", master)` and deleted `self.name = "white.png` and got this error: for k, v in cnf.items():
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'items'